# Is there a standard "magazine" size for printing?

Tags: print-design, adobe-indesign

**I'm thinking of printing a informational project in magazine size, however I have a hard time finding what the standard size for magazines is?**

There is no default size for this in InDesign and from what I've read there is no specific standard size, but I wanna ask anyway.

If there is some default template out there or anyone willing to share, I would really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 5):

Last time I was in Europe, magazine size was not on my mind... however, what I would do in a case like this is go to a kiosk or magazine stand, or even the nearest library, and measure one that was in the format I had in mind. The British mags I see around here look to be larger than A4, but they may not be typical.

Comment: Yes, however I would very much like to have the margins for bleed and text as well and those numbers aren't in the actual magazine as they're being stripped in the printing process. :)

Comment: I second "measure what's on the newsstand." Ask your printer (or query a few) about the margins and bleed. In the U.S. I usually use p9 bleed and 2p to 3p for margins.

Comment: Bleed is something to talk to your printer about. In fact, you *must* discuss the entire project with your print provider before you start, in as much detail as possible. There are many things besides bleed that you need to ensure are correct.

Comment: ^^Alan, we should make that a macro and paste it into every answer that has to do with printing. "First, talk to your printer."

Comment: Truth! Applies to the web, too: "First, talk to your developer!" for folks that don't do the code themselves.

Comment: In addition to bleed, you need to take into account creep. Like bleed, this is typically an adjustment done on the pre-press side and not in your actual design document itself.